# Need to automate Magento website

Tags: magento2, testing, automation, selenium

Can any one please tell me what is the difference between automating through MTAF and normal Selenium + TestNG?

What can I achieve from MTAF which I can't achieve using Selenium+ Java+ TestNG ?

Thanks for your help